# Wordpress - Using desktop CSS for mobile devices

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing up a child theme for my WordPress site. It works fine on the desktop but when I browse it on my Android mobile, it seems to ignore the CSS.

How do I make the theme as such that WordPress uses my desktop theme on the mobile?

I tried looking for the `meta viewport` tag but don't have it in my theme. Also, tried setting the `media query` but that doesn't seem to do much either. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be that my Android (and probably other mobile devices have the same behavior) was not resolving the hostname of my computer on the local network. Hence no CSS file was being served. Tried using an absolute URL and that loaded up the theme.